# Delete * from two tables inner join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

hello to all I have created in my project two tables that have the same id, the structure of the tables is this:

campagne:

```
id_campagna

data_inizio

data_fine
```

and table campagne_cliente

```
id_campagna_cliente

cliente_id_campagna

impianto_id_campagna
```

my will is to delete all the data contained in the two tables when the id

```
id_campagna

id_campagna_cliente
```

are the same.

also place the elimination procedure, from the table where they are shown all the data I have to select: id_campagna_cliente

in this way:

```
<a href="#elimina<?php echo $row['id_campagna_cliente']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-pin "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> <i class='fa fa-remove' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
```

this is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="elimina<?php echo $row['id_campagna_cliente']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Elimina Impianto</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <?php

             $elimina=mysqli_query($connessione,"select * from campagne_cliente where id_campagna_cliente='".$row['id_campagna_cliente']."'");


             $row_due=mysqli_fetch_array($elimina);

            ?>


            <div class="modal-body mx-3">

            <h5 style="text-align: center;">Eliminare Campagna di:&nbsp;<?php echo $row_due['nome'].'&nbsp;'?>?</h5>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="elimina.php?id_campagna_cliente=<?php echo $row['id_campagna_cliente']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Elimina</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the delete page from which I recover with $ _GET:     id_campagna_cliente

```
<?php

include '../../connessione.php';

$id_campagna_cliente=$_GET['id_campagna_cliente'];

mysqli_query($connessione,"DELETE * FROM campagne 

LEFT JOIN campagne_cliente 

ON campagne.id_campagna=campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente 

WHERE campagne.id_campagna = '$id_campagna_cliente'");

header('location: campagne.php');



?>
```

but when I run delete it does not happen anything like it?
I would like to delete all the data contained in these two tables

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why did you reopen this?? The duplicate is clear.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry, but the case you sent me is a user who asks when his parameters are null, my case is different

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Your duplicate links were way off from both the title and what the OP is asking.  There _is_ a duplicate for this question, but it's not what you marked, and I would be on the fence as to whether to mark this a duplicate.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry again but kindly I'm not understanding what is happening I was reported a question as a duplicate with -1, when it is not, why?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen DELETE campagne, campagne_cliente
FROM campagne campagne_cliente
LEFT JOIN campagne_cliente campagne_cliente
    ON campagne.id_campagna = campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente 
WHERE
    campagne.id_campagna = '$id_campagna_cliente' not work

Comment: @A.M That comment doesn't belong as a comment, it belongs in your question, which already contains this information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen forgive me but I did not understand what you said, my bad english fault, sorry

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you many sir for your help, now everything works, thank you again it was very kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete from multiple target tables using a delete join, then you need to specify all tables or aliases which you want to delete.  Something like this should work:

```
DELETE ca, cc
FROM campagne ca
LEFT JOIN campagne_cliente cc
    ON ca.id_campagna = cc.id_campagna_cliente 
WHERE
    ca.id_campagna = ?;
```

You would then bind some value for `id_campagna` in your PHP, ideally using a PHP prepared statement.

Note that `DELETE *` is not valid as you were using it; only aliases are allowed to follow `DELETE`, and then only in the context of a multi-table delete.